# Can a Postgres C-language function reference a stateful variable C-side (possibly in a thread safe manner)?

Tags: c, postgresql, function

I am currently attempting to compute random values drawn from a beta distribution QUICKLY. I have a slow solution in PLV8, but I know that randomkit/mtrand from numpy (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/random/mtrand) is bloody quick and entirely extractable. In light of this, I have shamelessly taken the files *randomkit.h*, *randomkit.c*, *ditributions.h*, and *ditributions.c* from that repository and created a C-language function with the following code:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "randomkit.h"
#include "distributions.h"

/*
-- DIRECTORY is path our library resides in.
CREATE FUNCTION pg_random_from_beta(DOUBLE PRECISION, DOUBLE PRECISION)  
    RETURNS DOUBLE PRECISION
    AS 'DIRECTORY/funcs', 'pg_random_from_beta'
    LANGUAGE C STRICT
*/

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

Datum pg_random_from_beta(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(pg_random_from_beta);
Datum
pg_random_from_beta(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    rk_state    rkstate;
    rk_randomseed(&rkstate);

    float8  alpha   = PG_GETARG_FLOAT8(0);
    float8  beta    = PG_GETARG_FLOAT8(1);
    PG_RETURN_FLOAT8(rk_beta(&rkstate, alpha, beta));
}
```

This compiles and works nicely, except that randomly generating a new `rkstate` on each function call really degrades from the performance of the function. Is there a way to create the `rkstate`stateful variable once and reference it subsequent times? I envision that this could be done using `static` variables, but that is unlikely to be thread safe. Is there a better solution?

Comment: If the problem of replacing part of randomkit library with a function that generates a random unsigned long generated by postgres is easier, I am all for that as well. Been poking around and having very little luck.

Comment: OK, I've managed to link into postgres's random() function. So I don't need the state anymore, but now its really slow... so the original question still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed store state across functions. The `PG_FUNCTION_ARGS` macros unpacks to `FunctionCallInfoData* fcinfo` (see `src/include/fmgr.h`), where the `FmgrInfo *flinfo` member has a member `void *fn_extra`.

You can cache things between calls by `MemoryContextAlloc`ing memory for a struct and stashing a pointer to the struct in that space. You *must* use the context specified by `fn_mcxt`, do *not* use `palloc`.

See `src/backend/utils/fmgr/README` and existing usage of `fn_extra` per `git grep`. It's a bit confusing, since `fn_extra` is documented as being for use by *function call handlers* but in practice is often used by function implementations themselves. I've [posted a patch to amend the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAMsr+YGiK5ZukbdB+dLVLzB13y7eZ42iDMYZEmmiT8N5HR-wcQ@mail.gmail.com).

For example, see the type caching done in `src/backend/utils/adt/arrayfuncs.c`.

Thread safety is irrelevant because PostgreSQL uses a multi-processing copy-on-write model using `fork()` and POSIX shared memory. Each backend is single threaded. It's possible to share between backends, but you have to use the extension shared memory mechanism, and the data being shared must make sense when copied between processes. In your case it's not likely to make any sense to do this, and you should just initialize `rk_state` on first use in your backend.

Because PostgreSQL is single threaded, you can also share state between functions (where `fn_extra` won't help you) simply by *declaring and accessing a global variable*. You must be careful about the memory context you use if you allocate memory for this variable using `palloc` or `MemoryContextAlloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out, postgres's internal `random()` function can be accessed to get random longs. I was able to replace `rk_random()` with `random()`, negating the need for the stateful variable. Unfortunately, this hasn't worked out as well as I hoped, the speed of the function call is many orders of magnitude slower than when I had timed the randomkit library myself, so thats a bit of a bummer.

I don't have answer to my original question, so I if anybody wants to address that, I will mark it the right answer!